# Sending POST request weird issue

Tags: angularjs

I'm quite new with ANGULAR and web development in general and I'm currently working on a web tool. Now I want this tool to send a POST request to a web service but Im encountering a weird bug. Now I have below code in my javascript:

```
var data_info = { test_id: 'TEST', model_id: 'TEST:TEST_ID' };
//data_info = JSON.stringify(data_info);

var request_json = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
    data: data_info,
    cache: false,
};

console.log(request_json);
$http(request_json).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // response code here
}
```

Now this code currently doesn't pass the preflight request check and is always returning a 405. But if I change the line **data: data_info** in the request JSON into a new key let's say **body: data_info** it now successfully sends the request and I can confirm that the service is receiving it. I'm not sure what's the issue here and can't figure it out.

Comment: it has to be server side fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your header to :

```
headers : {
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
}
```

Please try

Comment: Thanks a lot. That fixes the issue.